# Xming fails to display Quartus II 9.0

Tags: ssh, remote-access, x11

Attempting to run Altera Quartus II (2) 9.0 on a remote RHEL5 Linux (2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 kernel 64-bit) box over a SSH connection via PuTTY 0.62 and a local Xming 6.9.0.31 X server running on Windows XP/Win7.

I have set PuTTY up to forward X11 and successfully remotely run other X programs on this server.

If I use Cygwin/X X server, Quartus II 9.0 displays correctly.

Xming X server does not report any visible errors on the command line; it just seems to hang after displaying an initial blank, white box.

Is this a known issue with Altera Quartus II 9.0 and Xming? Is it possible to know the root cause of the incompatibility?

Answer (score 0):

When using X11 remotely over putty, I usually get similar results unless compression is enabled (in the putty settings somewhere). Not sure if it'll solve your issue, but it's worth doing regardless...

Comment: Thanks Alex. I believe I found this setting under Settings > Connection > SSH, then select option Enable Compression. Unfortunately, this did not solve this problem.